# Is there a Problem of comptability with my tags?

Tags: html, css

there is someting I don't understund, i'm creating the footer,but I can't align my tag **li** with the tag **h3** so, My choice is it good for the footer ? what could be the solution ? What could be the solution ? I send a print of my desk with html and css too, Thanks all !

i send the code html and css but i can't post picture, sorry

```
`html`
  

<footer>
     <nav id="mentionlegal">
        <div class="Felement1">
           <h3>A propos</h3>
           <ul>
              <li>Fonctionnement du site</li>
              <li>Conditions générales de vente</li>
              <li>Données et confidentialité</li>
           </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="Felement2">
           <h3>Nos hébergements</h3>
           <ul>
              <li>Charte qualité</li>
              <li>Soumettre votre hôtel</li>
           </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="Felement3">
           <h3>Assistance</h3>
           <ul>
              <li>Centre d'aide</li>
              <li>Nous contacter</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </nav>
      </footer>

    'css'
    /* Début du Footer*/
    #mentionlegal
    {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: space-between;
        border: 2px solid black;
        width: 1200px;
        height: 220px;     
    }
```

Comment: Align how? Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, i need align in vertical*

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your css

```
#mentionlegal ul {
   padding: 0;
}
#mentionlegal ul li {
   list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, i try this directly

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is working,
It was so simple, and I spend two hours on this ^^'